# ng --version pops the VS code instead of giving the version it opens a file called ng.js whenever I run any ng command

Tags: json, angular, version, serve

I tried deleting it with all cache and installing node js npm -g and angular all over againn I run the commands in cmd as administratore I tried vs code cmd terminal and powershell but all in vain I did that multiple of times I checked every possible solution.

I want to install angular correctly and becable to use ng